# Dynamically renaming excel sheets

Tags: vba, excel

From a previous question, to dynamically rename a sheet based on a cell reference changing, you use this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address(False, False) = "C3" Then ActiveSheet.name = 
ActiveSheet.Range("C3")
End Sub
```

But this does not work if the cell ("C3") is in sheet 1 but is itself referencing a cell on another sheet - let's say C3 is referencing "A1" in "sheet 2".

How can you change the code so when you edit A1 in sheet 2, the name of sheet 1 automatically updates?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to be clear - A1 needs to be able to be edited multiple times, not just once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or place this code on Sheet1 Module...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
On Error Resume Next
Sheet1.Name = Range("C3").Value
End Sub
```

Note: Sheet1 here is the Sheet Code Name.
So each time the value of A1 changes on Sheet2, the Sheet1 will be renamed.

Comment: Hi sktneer - sorry I'm a novice. On Sheet1 I've gone on "view code", and "insert -> module", and pasted in your code - and nothing seems to happen. What am I doing wrong? Sorry for the beginner's question.

Answer (score 2):

Add the code below in the `Worksheet_Change` event in "Sheet2" worksheet module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

' only run the code if the cell being modified is in cell "A1"
If Not Intersect(Range("A1"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Name = Target.Value
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: HI Shai - thanks for this. Works perfectly for one edit of "A1", but if you edit it a second time, the "Sheet1" reference is no longer valid as Sheet1 is now called whatever you edited A1 to be the first time. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @DDT you can add a variable, let's say `OldShtName`, and save the worksheet's name before the change, and later use it `Worksheets(OldShtName).Name = Target.Value`

Comment: really appreciate the reply. Sadly you've just gone over my skill level (very low, as you may have guessed) - can you explain a little more basically, if you have time?

Comment: @DDT this was not in your Post. If you want you can open a new post, and describe exactly what you are trying to achieve.